# How to load javascript files dinamically on server side rendered website?

Tags: javascript

There is a website with a lot of javascript files. Website uses no framework just webpack, jquery and other plugins which are installed through npm. Just simple html site and laravel for backend.

All javascript files are required to main.js. And main.js files is added to template html file.

How to load for each page only files that are needed for that page? For example if you visit contact us page client should load only contact.js file without other files like products.js, register.js and etc.

Ofcourse I could include each js file to its page without loading all js files in one file. But maybe there is smarter way how it could be implemented on my situation from javascript and webpack side?

Now my javascript file size is 2mb, some pages needs only small part of it. So, I need for each page load only what is needed for it.

Comment: Are you using React?

Comment: No framework. Just classical server side rendered html and webpack for managing css and js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a classical server, then I don't think it's possible. With a Javascript library like React, you could've considered code splitting.

I think your initial approach, which was splitting them into their respective `.js` files is, as it stands now, the best approach

Answer (score 1):

May you use RequireJs ? It will optimize your Code &' Performance